# Is there a way to declare background-size-height?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to declare background-size-height, or something close to that?

I want the background image to fit 100% height but keep it's proportions, aka width still dynamic.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article on CSS Tricks for info on making a full-screen background image.
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

And this link to W3Schools for info on the background-size css property.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: @fancy Mark it as your answer :)

Comment: First link is broken. Please include pertinent info inside your answer to avoid this kind of issue :)